# How can I open the bookmark icon of a picture instead of the piction itself?

Tags: bookmarks

I have a few important pictures which to me are currupt. When I open them I only see a grey appearance.
However, when I am in the windows explorer and hit View->Large icons, just very briefly I do see the preview of the picture. I would like to know where I can find this preview. This must be a 30 kb version of the picture stored somewhere.

If anybody has an idea, let me know:)

Cheers,
Greg

The file for reference: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=63761408492956032490

Comment: The preview will be in your thumbs.db temp file which gets created in folders that contain images.

Comment: The file you uploaded does appear to be very corrupt - there is not even a JFIF marker at the start. I haven't tried it, but [Thumbcache Viewer](https://thumbcacheviewer.github.io/) says it can extract the images from Windows' icon cache.

Answer (score 1):

see the Thumbs.db section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache)

> Thumbs.db files are stored in each directory that contains thumbnails on Windows systems.

This file is hidden so you have to enable visibility of hidden files to get there.

you can then use [thumbnail viewer](http://www.itsamples.com/thumbnail-database-viewer.html)  or [thumb cache viewer](https://thumbcacheviewer.github.io/) (mentioned in the comment above) to extract the images from this database

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks lipek! Thumbnail is probably exactly what I need!
I went to the directory in your link at %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
and indeed there are some database files. Would you have time to explain how I get to the thumbnail picture? 
Cheers!

Comment: Greg: I modified my original answer. if it helped you please click up arrow. thanks